# Junit Testing on Android Application

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I am currently doing the Android Application testing on JUnit in Eclipse, I am facing problem. I am have 2 class files in the abc package. test1.java and com.test.java. test1.java is playing role on read a text file and retrieve the test cases in the text file and store in array. While, com.test.java is a file that will run the automated black box testing on the android application. My problem is i am not able to pass the value from test1.java to the method test file for testing.

below are my code

```
  test1.java
 package com.calculator.test;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.util.Random;

  import android.util.Log;

 public class test1 {
private static int j;

static String[] jeff = new String[] { "2", "2", "4"};

public static void main(String[] args) {



}

public static String[] data() {
    String[] lines = new String[0];
    String path = "C:/Users/Sony/workspace/calculator1.Test/testing1.txt";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(path);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
                file)));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lines = add(line, lines);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("error msg", e.getMessage());
    }

    return lines;
}

public String[] getDataFromAsset()
{
    return null;


}
private static String[] add(String s, String[] array) {
    int len = array.length;
    String[] temp = new String[len + 1];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, temp, 0, len);
    temp[len] = s;
    return temp;
}

public static String print(String[] data) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int rand = random.nextInt(data.length);
    // System.out.println("Random no = " + rand + " -> " + data[rand]);
    String bbb = tes1t(data[rand]);
    //return "1 2 3"
    return bbb;

}

public static String tes1t(String data) {
    String law = data;
    String[] jeff = data.split("\\s");
    for (int j = 0; j < jeff.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(jeff[j]);
        if (j < jeff.length - 1)
            System.out.print(", ");
        else
            System.out.println();

    }
    String aaa = getdata1(jeff);
    //System.out.println(jeff[1]);
    return aaa;
}

public static String getdata1(String[] x) {

    String ss = x[1];
    //System.out.println(ss);
    return ss;
}
```

}

```
com.test.java


package com.calculator.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.calculator.Main;
import com.calculator.R;
import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;

public class calculatorMainTests extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Main> {
private Solo solo;

public calculatorMainTests() {
    super(Main.class);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}

public void testDisplayBlackBox() {
    Log.d("Test 1", "started");


    //String[] ddd = test1.data();
    //String ccc = test1.print(ddd);

    solo.enterText(0, ccc);

    // Enter 20 in first editfield
    solo.enterText(1, "2");

    // Click on Multiply button
    solo.clickOnButton("Multiply");

    // Verify that resultant of 10 x 20
    assertTrue(solo.searchText("4"));

}

public void testDisplayBlackBox1() {

    Log.d("Test 2", "started");
    // Enter 10 in first editfield
    solo.enterText(0, "1");

    // Enter 20 in first editfield
    solo.enterText(1, "20");

    // Click on Multiply button
    solo.clickOnButton("Multiply");

    // Verify that resultant of 10 x 20
    assertTrue(solo.searchText("20"));

}



@Override
protected void tearDown() throws Exception {

    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
}
}
```

Comment: Define "not able"? can explain in more detail?thx

Comment: you say you are "not able" to pass a value from a test1.java to the "method test file". can you elaborate ?

Comment: mean when i run the junit test for com.test, the data that inside test1 cannot be passed to com. test. In the textfile- testing1.txt, there are a few test cases: for eg: 1(input1) 2(input2) 3(expected output). i store the 1 2 3 in array  and then in com.test.java i want to retrieve the value for my testing. but cant get the value and   error show cant read the testing1.txt. thx.

Comment: so your issue is not at all about passing data from a class to another, but rather to read your computer file system from your android device/emulator ?